# Show Self-closed element property by xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to show the property of tag Page, like this xml:

```
<format class="Book">BookTitle </format>Test <page number="51" />….... </p>
```

I have this xslt for convert xml to html

```
<xsl:template match="format" name="format">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="name() = 'format'" >
        <xsl:if test ="@class = 'q'">
          <xsl:call-template name="q" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test ="@class = 'Book'">
          <xsl:call-template name="Book" />
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="Book" name=" Book">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="page" name="page">
        <xsl:value-of select="@number" />
  </xsl:template>
```

But, attribute of tag Page is not displayed, because this tag is as child of tag Book
 What should I do?

Comment: I added a leading `<p>` to your XML and tested your code. Its output is `BookTitle Test 51…....` which seems to be ok. So what is the desired behavior/output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="Book" name=" Book">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="page" name="page">
    <xsl:value-of select="@number" />
</xsl:template>
```

Change to

```
<xsl:template match="Book" name=" Book">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page" name="page">
<xsl:value-of select=" @number"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank`s for your help. but it does not work properly

Comment: Edit my answer please check

Comment: Exactly I want to convert this xml:
<format class="Book">BookTitle </format>Test <page number="51" />….... </p>
to this html:
BookTitle Test 51 ...

Comment: @MojtabaLajevardi check it